# Android Set Imageview position without anim

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I have this Imageview 
**activity1.xml**

```
       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logobrand"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

with this result

[image]

i animate it with this animation 
**anim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-35%p"
    android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

So i obtains that :

[image]

but in my other activity with how can i have the same position of my ImageView without use animation ?
**Activity2.xml**

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:src="@drawable/logobrand"
      android:visibility="visible" />
```

Because when i tried i obtains that...

[image]

**I search to have same position of my imageview between both activities
Thanks**

Comment: `android:layout_centerHorizontal` shouldn't be `android:layout_centerVertical` instead?

Comment: Sounds like you need to mimick the resulting position of the animated image in the second activity.
Could you not just change height to wrap_content and use marginTop to achieve the same position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in both activities replace `android:layout_height="300dp"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
and add in second activity`android:layout_marginto="Xdp"` to look like first activity !

**activity1.xml**

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:src="@drawable/logobrand"
  android:visibility="visible" />
```

**activity2.xml**

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
  android:src="@drawable/logobrand"
  android:visibility="visible" />
```

hope it's help

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate marginTop for your layout (no need to change any thing) using this :

```
   // waiting for layout to be created.
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // top of your logo when when center vertical
            int originalPosition = iV1.getTop();
            System.out.println("original position :: " + originalPosition);

            // vertical upward shift using your animation property
            int verticalShift = (int) (parentView.getHeight() * 0.35f);    
            System.out.println("vertical shift :: " + verticalShift);

            // final margin from top
            int marginTop = originalPosition - verticalShift;
            System.out.println("actual margin top :: " + marginTop);

            // testing it on another view
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) iV2
                    .getLayoutParams();
            lp.setMargins(0, originalPosition - verticalShift, 0, 0);

            iV2.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }
    }, 100);
```

I hope this will help.